# $fillable must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have following laravel model. When I try to visit the site it shows the following error.

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
> Type of App\Models\Setting::$fillable must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)

**Environment information**

Laravel version: 8.60.0

PHP version: 7.4.16

```
<?php
        namespace App\Models;
        
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
        
        class Setting extends Model
        {
            use HasFactory;
        
            protected array $fillable = [
                'key',
                'value',
            ];
        
            protected $casts = [
                'value' => 'array',
            ];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the ... "*Type of App\Models\Setting::$fillable must not be defined*". So change:

```
protected array $fillable = [
                'key',
                'value',
            ];
```

to

```
protected $fillable = [
                'key',
                'value',
            ];
```

where its type is not defined.

[Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)